# pip install of a package from a manually created repository is failing

Tags: python, pip

I have created a python repository on machine 10.x.x.x and it's accessible over a web browser (set up an Apache server).

I am verifying its successful operation from a different machine and it's failing with the error mentioned below

```
[root@localhost ~]# pip install --index-url=http://10.x.x.x/repos/python/python2 -r requirement.txt --trusted-host 10.x.x.x
Looking in indexes: http://10.x.x.x/repos/python/python2
Collecting Flask==1.0.2 (from -r requirement.txt (line 1))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==1.0.2 (from -r requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask==1.0.2 (from -r requirement.txt (line 1))
[root@localhost ~]#
```

The requirement file has the package

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat requirement.txt
Flask==1.0.2
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Python version is 2.7.5 and the pip version on both the repository machine and the test machine are as follows:

```
# pip -V
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You're asking pip to install Flask v1.0.2 from your package index, and pip's saying it can't find it there.  Is Flask in your index or not?

Comment: Use `--extra-index-url` instead of `--index-url`.

Comment: @hoefling. thanks for the response. i tested your suggestion but it unfortunately fails .Starting new HTTP connection (1): 10.23.174.40
http://10.23.174.40:80 "GET /repos/python/python2/pip/ HTTP/1.1" 404 223
Could not fetch URL http://10.23.174.40/repos/python/python2/pip/: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://10.23.174.40/repos/python/python2/pip/ - skipping
I am not sure , why it is attempting to lookup  http://10.23.174.40/repos/python/python2/pip/
is it trying to lookup pip.cfg ?

Comment: @jwodder . the pacakge is available and it is as follows .[root@repo4vc python2]# pwd
/var/www/html/repos/python/python2
[root@repo4vc python2]# ls | grep -i flask
Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
[root@repo4vc python2]#

Comment: Can you run `pip install Flask --verbose --extra-index-url=http://10.x.x.x/repos/python/python2 --trusted-host 10.x.x.x` and add the output to the question?

Comment: @hoefling
  The output is quite lengthy and is consuming more than what the comment box can handle . please let me know if there is an alternate way of sharing this with you . thank you

Comment: Use pastebin.com or similar service for sharing long texts.